# request.get doesn't work in python scraper

Tags: python, get, web-scraping, python-requests, scraper

Hi I am trying to make this basic scraper work, where it should go to a website fill "City" and "area" ,search for restaurants and return the html page.

This is the code i'm using

```
payload = OrderedDict([('cityId','NewYork'),('area','Centralpark')])

req = requests.get("http://www.somewebsite.com",params=payload)

f = req.content 
soup = BeautifulSoup((f))
```

And Here is how the Source HTML looks like

[image]

When I'm checking the resulting soup variable it doesn't have the search results , instead it contains the data from the first page only,which has the form for entering city and area value (i.e. www.somewebsite.com, what i want is results of `www.somewebsite.com?cityId=NewYork&area=centralPark`).So Is there anything that i have to pass with that params to explicitly press the search button or is there any other way to make it work.

Comment: I think that you are using the wrong GET URL! In the form `action` is `/location-suggestions`. So your url should be something like this `www.somewebsite.com/location-suggestions?cityId=NewYork&area=centralPar`

Comment: So what do you suggest i do ...i tried changing my url to somewebsite.com/location-suggestions , but no change in results

Comment: Maybe the webstie you are trying to scrape require a valid cookies. Try to create a `session` and use it then for the `GET` request. Sorry I can't do more without the website to test on i!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first check whether you can visit the URL by web browser and get the correct result.

Comment: The Url formed by get request fills up the "city" and "area" field , but the search is not done (as in we'll see the result after we press the search button)...So how do i get the search result from there